# Multicharacter command-line arguments with a ruby script

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, optparse

Normally I would use [optparse](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html) to parse command-line arguments. In this case I need arguments like `-ssh` or `-telnet` (basically I need the arguments from [PuTTY](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)). Optparse only supports single letter flags with a long version (e.g. `-s` and `--ssh`).

Is there another class like optparse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Slop](http://github.com/leejarvis/slop) will work for me. Thanks to [Boris Pilgun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306709/boris-pilgun)

Answer (score 0):

Try [commander gem](https://github.com/commander-rb/commander)
It supports both - short and (or) long versions of parameters and is very flexible and well documented.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for arguments like `-ssh`. Do you have an example?

Comment: @BenediktBock hmm, looks like I misunderstood your needs initially, sorry. It looks like `commander` doesn't support such kind of arguments. Check this gems collection also https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers, not sure but might be you'll find something useful there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple/pragmatic approach: if you are unhappy with the implementation of the OptionParser, I recommend you write your own parser using [`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#ARGV).